# file creation failing in php

Tags: php

I am learning file handling in php. I have written the following code to create file:

```
<?php
    $fileName = "testFile.txt";
    $fileHandle = fopen($fileName,"w") or die ("can't open file");
    fclose($fileHandle);
    phpinfo();
?>
```

The problem is I am getting "can't open file". I changed the permission of the directory containing this file and all the files in the directory to 777 still the problem persists.
Can somebody please help me in solving this issue?
Thanks

Comment: your code is fine. check that fopen is not disabled in php.ini

Comment: @galchen the php.ini already has allow_url_fopen = On by default I guess, Is there some other place in php.in which has to be enabled?

Comment: check to see if disable_functions = ... is set to have fopen (i doubt it'll be there though). did you try opening a file for read only and fetching data?

Comment: I got the solution, the directory had all the correct permissions and the path to the directory was correct but I ran out of space allocated to me by the server, I removed some files and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using an absolute path for the $filename

```
$fileName = "/path/to/file/testFile.txt";
```

or you can change dir prior to opening the file

```
chdir('/path/to/file');
```

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

AMENDED ANSWER, TRY THIS

```
<?php
    $path = "/path/to/file";
    $fileName = "testFile.txt";

    if (! file_exists($path)) {
        die ("$path doesn't exist");
    }

    $fileHandle = fopen("$path/$fileName","w") or die ("can't open file");

    fclose($fileHandle);
    phpinfo();
```

Comment: @Shankhoneer see amended answer

Answer (score 1):

is the php script and file in the same folder?
if not you need to specify the relative path to the testFile.txt

Comment: aha bumperbox is faster than me :D

Comment: I am trying to create the file so I guess file should be created in the same folder as that of the script

Comment: how if you omit the die part:

$fileHandle = fopen($fileName,"w");

see what error it came up?

i would say it's permission problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fileHandle = fopen( dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $fileName , 'w' )  ....
```